# Is this server core intallation possible: DC + SQL + Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core

I would like to setup a test staging virtual server. If at all possible I'd like to use just one virtual machine. These are the software requirements:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Domain controller
- Web Server
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- Sharepoint Foundation 2010

I know this is possible to setup on a single machine. The question is: **Is it possible to set this up on a server core machine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SQL Server IIRC does not install on server core. Sharepoint is another candidate.

Comment: Well Sharepoint is basically just a web application... But a standalone installation may be a problem because of SQL Express...

Comment: Technically yes, but you ahve to go around the installer. Not sure that works. But anyhow, SQL is an issue here anyway.

Comment: I have SQL Server 2008 R2 running fine on R2 Server core, at least the database engine. Reporting services will not work though.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint won't work unfortunately, IIS will run, however you can only serve static web pages as ASP.net cannot be installed on Server Core.

More details on this page at [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.geekofalltrades.aspx?pr=blog).

Server core is a great technology for infrastructure rolls however is very limited when it comes to installing applications.

The following taken from the MCTS 70-640 Documentation:
"As an overview; Sever Core supports nine rolls:

- AD DS
- AD LDS
- DHCP Server
- DNS Server
- File Services
- Print Services
- Streaming Media Services
- IIS (Without ASP.net)
- Hyper-V

It also supports eleven optional features:

- MS Failover Cluster
- Network Load Balancing
- Subsystem for UNIX based applications
- Windows Backup
- Multipath I/O
- Removable Storage Management
- Windows Bitlocker Drive Encryption
- SNMP
- WINS
- Telnet Client
- QoS"

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. :) They both provide valuable info but about a different aspect...

Comment: Technically NOT correct. ASP.NET will work with 2008 R2. This was an issue on 2008, but it was solvedwith 2008 R2 (the server .net farmework now has no references to client technologies that are not available on server coew, like wpf, winforms partially). I suggest updating your knowlege to current technology. Check http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/11/24/asp-net-supported-on-server-core-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: Ok so this one's related to Windows Server 2008 and **not R2**. Thanks @TomTom for pointing it out.